# Am I misunderstanding pointer ref/deref, pointer arithmetic or do leading 0's really make a difference in C's ability to detect equality?

Tags: c, pointers, hex

I've been trying to understand an error I get with the following code

```
bytes2bits(p,q,pixels)
u_char *p, *q;
register u_int pixels;
{
  register u_char *r, a;
  register u_long *l;

   ...

switch (*l++) {
    case 0x00000000:    a = 0x00; break;
    case 0x00000001:    a = 0x10; break;
    case 0x00000100:    a = 0x20; break;
    case 0x00000101:    a = 0x30; break;

    case 0x00010000:    a = 0x40; break;
    case 0x00010001:    a = 0x50; break;
    case 0x00010100:    a = 0x60; break;
    case 0x00010101:    a = 0x70; break;

    case 0x01000000:    a = 0x80; break;
    case 0x01000001:    a = 0x90; break;
    case 0x01000100:    a = 0xa0; break;
    case 0x01000101:    a = 0xb0; break;

    case 0x01010000:    a = 0xc0; break;
    case 0x01010001:    a = 0xd0; break;
    case 0x01010100:    a = 0xe0; break;
    case 0x01010101:    a = 0xf0; break;

    default:
      (void) fprintf(stderr,"bytes2bits: bad value %x\n",*--l);
      exit(1);
}

    ......
```

}

My problem lies in the fact that this block of code exits with the error message

```
bytes2bits: bad value 1010100
```

I would've thought that 0x01010100 == 1010100 (Note: the fprintf is using %x as output format, so I am looking at a hexadecimal number. Also, when I test and use a printf with %d output format, I see the value 16843008 (= 16^6 + 16^4 + 16^2), which is the equivalent decimal representation of 0x01010100. The 'bad value' 1010100 output is not affected by the presence of my printf checking statement).

```
bytes2bits: bad value 1010100
```

How can I make sense of the fact that the switch statement does not recognize 1010100 as the next to last case (i.e.case 0x01010100: a = 0xe0)?

Comment: 1) stick with unsigned types; dont use "%d". 2) Use array indexing instead of pointer fiddling: `printf ("Decimal Rep: %lu\n", (unsigned) l[-1] ));`

Comment: @wildplasser: Why not say "use %u instead of %d"?

Comment: The code is pre-existing. My only modification was the printf. I suppose it would've been more consistent to use %u format, and I may as well check that, but the decimal value still corresponds to the hex value. So I think the %d didn't confuse anything. (But I'll check to be sure)

Comment: You're also casting your `u_long` value to an `int`. While that may not necessarily cause issues, doing an unsigned->signed conversion from a data type that may be larger to a datatype that may be smaller isn't a very good idea.

Comment: I would also suggest to do the swich on a masked value, since *l is unsigned long : `switch (*l++ & 0xff) {...}`

Comment: No, he is only testing 8 bits so it seems. If higher bits were set, he would land in the default: department.

Comment: Changing the output format of the printf doesn't change the decimal output. Actually, eliminating the printf entirely doesn't change the essential problem. I just used the printf to make certain the hex value I was seeing was really the hex value I thought I was seeing

Comment: Could you state the *intention* of the above fragment? Are you decoding an interlaced bit-pattern ?(such as morton addressing)

Comment: Is the size of `u_long` the same as size of `int` on your platform?

Comment: @wildplasser The intent seems to be to be to code/decode values read from a file. I'm trying to resurrect some old code here

Comment: @AndreyT - Just tested sizes. u_long is 8 bytes, int is 4 bytes.

Comment: @user1245262: So, here you go. Case closed.

Comment: Just a note. You should remove the old K&R cruft and put proper function declarations and definitions. A lot of compilers do not check the types as thoroughly with K&R syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reasonable guess here is that on your platform the `u_long` that you analyze with `switch` is longer than `int`/`unsigned int` that you are actually printing.

For example, if `u_long` is a 64 bit type and `int` is a 32-bit type, then  your `*l++` might evaluate to `0xBAADF00D01010100`. This obviously will not match the `case 0x01010100:` label. But when you are doing your `printf`s with `%x` specifier, you are only printing the trailing `0x01010100` portion.

Use `l` prefix in format specifiers (`%lx`, `%ld` etc.) to print `long` values to avoid such confusions in the future (assuming that `u_long` is based on `long`).

Comment: If you compile with gcc put -W -Wall in your command line, the compiler would have warned that the `printf` format specifier didn't match.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are on a platform where the size of u_long is not as expected (e.g. a 64 bit word). So *l may take a value bigger than the 32-bit patterns you are testing, and the "%d" and "%x" format could truncate to 32 bit the actual value. I suggest you to print the sizeof(*l).

Comment: I think this may be it. printf ("SG Checker byte2bit a: sizeof(u_long) %d\n",(int) sizeof(u_long));  gave an output of "sizeof(u_long) 8", which I assume means u_long is 8 bytes. What I'm doing here is resurrecting some old software with its own funny codecs, so what I'm going to try is forcing l to be a 32 bit integer.

Comment: @user1245262 Then replace the usage of an u_long with unsigned int in your code. Or better yet, use the uint32_t type from <stdint.h>.  When you're printing a 64 bit value with %d, %u or %x, you're not printing the actual value of your u_long.

Comment: @user1245262: Maybe you should instead fix the typedef to make `u_long` a `uint32_t`, if there's a lot of code that assumes it will be 32 bits...

Comment: @nos: are you in my head, or my alter ego?

Comment: Switching u_long to int32_t seems to do the trick (Oops - should've been uint32_t, but not really a major issue. I think the use of unsigned ints was arbitrary)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: (hope I got it right this time ;-)

```
a= (*l &         1) << 4
 | (*l &     0x100) >> 3
 | (*l &   0x10000) >> 10
 | (*l & 0x1000000) >> 17
 ;
if ( *l & 0xfefefefe) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Badstuff: %lx\n", (unsigned long) *l);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 l++;
```

Comment: No, the *l expression is 4 bytes (32 bits). The case/switch comparison values are all given in hex, since each hex digit is 4 bits, 8 hex digits are 32 bits. Also, the switch statement is being used for some sort of odd decoding, that I don't really want to mess with

Comment: @wildplasser: 0x01010101 = 16843009

Comment: @user1245262: Are you sure `*l` is 32 bits and not 64 bits? Oh, I see that it is actually 64 bits. So, here's your answer.